# Animated Drawings In Patents

Tags: video, animated, file

Can you submit an animated drawing to illustrate your invention in a non-provisional application?
If so, how?
Mike Z

Answer (score 1):

Common sense and experience would lead me to say "absolutely not", but when I searched through the [submission guidelines for drawings](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-getting-started/patent-basics/types-patent-applications/nonprovisional-utility-patent#heading-24), and although they heavily suggest it is not acceptable, I couldn't find anything explicitly barring this.

My next step was to get on the phone with the US Patent and Trademark Office (USPTO) and ask if animated drawings are allowed.  The answer I got was surprising:

*"The only requirement is that the document be submitted in PDF format and that drawings are in portrait orientation and 300dpi."*

**I don't fully trust this answer.**

1. As far as I know, it's wildly non-standard.  That alone could make it a sub-optimal choice.  If there is a problem, or if it's not allowed, you'll have to correct it, which will not kill the application, but if using an attorney, you would surely be billed for the extra work.
2. The [PCT rules referenced in the USPTO guidelines](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1825.html) are very specific and include physical requirements:

> (a) All elements of the international application (i.e., the request, the description, the claims, the drawings, and the abstract) shall be so presented as to admit of direct reproduction by photography, electrostatic processes, photo offset, and microfilming, in any number of copies.
> <sub>Source: [Appendix T - Patent Cooperation Treaty and Regulations Under the PCT | 11.2    Fitness for Reproduction](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/mpep-9025-appx-t.html#d0e366850)</sub>

Just the fact that there is a [dpi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) requirement suggests the documents must be printable.

3. The animation would not display in printed forms of the patent, and would not likely display on web versions of the patent, such as Google patents, [WIPO](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf), and the various national patent databases.
4. There is a technical risk.  [Although it *may* be possible to embed an animation in a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9009771/3400155), having that animation display properly on any given system, such as an examiner's, is far from guaranteed.  It may require the proper plugins.  Again not a fatal flaw, but one that will delay the process, and potentially drive up the cost.

On this last point in particularly, stick with the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.  Complications are useful [in limited contexts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complication_(horology)), and are best avoided in general.

Comment: How about flip book animation?  I've never seen that done, but haven't seen it prohibited either!

Comment: Flipbook would probably be ok, because it's a series of images, and would work in a printed format.